# Symplectic submanifolds of the tangent bundle $TM$ which have the form of a vector or fiber bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let  $(M,g)$  be  a Riemannian  manifold  which  admit a non vanishing  vector  field.(That is $\chi(M)=0$  when $M$ is  a compact  manifold). We  pull back The  symplectic  structure of  the  cotangent  bundle  to the  $2$-form  $\omega$ on $TM$.

> Is there necessarily  a  non vanishing  vector  field $X$ on $M$ for  which the  following submanifold of $(TM, \omega)$  would  be a  symplectic  submanifold?
>
> $$\{v_p\in TM \mid |v_p|=1, v_p \perp X(p)\}$$
>
> where $v_p$ is  a  vector in $TM$ based at point $p\in M$.

The  motivation for  this  question is the  following:

We  would  like  to  find  some  symplectic  submanifolds  of  $TM$ which  are in the  form of  a  sub vector bundle  of  the tangent  bundle  or  sub fiber bundle  of  unite tangent  bundle.

In the  standard coordinate $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$, the  elementary  examples  of  symplectic  submanifolds are $$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k,0,0,\ldots,0,y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_k,0,0\ldots,0)$$

In  such  elementary example  we loose  the  whole  base  space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably don't understand your question correctly, because the answer to the boxed question seems to be: obviously $X$ never exists if $M$ is compact. More generally, there is no closed manifold $V$ and map $f : V \to T^*M$ such that $f^*\omega$ is symplectic. Otherwise you would get an exact symplectic form on a closed manifold, and Stokes forbids this.

I can mention something that looks like what you wrote below the box. A cooriented hyperplane field $\xi$ on $M$ defines a submanifold $S\xi = \{\lambda ; \ker \lambda = \xi\} \subset T^* M$ (equality of cooriented hyperplanes) which is half a rank 1 subbundle. It is symplectic if and only if $\xi$ is contact.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer and your attention to my question.